# Sleep and check for a matching file (Bash) until it gets created

Tags: bash, jenkins, wildcard, sleep

I'm working on a shell script in Jenkins, that must check for a file every 2 minutes until it gets generated on a remote server. Once the file is found, the job must be successful. But in my case I am experiencing issues with my script, which is keep on sleeping every 2 minutes and not finding the matching file. I know that the issue is with wildcard. But is there any alternate way to fix this? my script:

```
while [ ! -f ${DONE_DIR}/issxxx*.xml ];
do
    sleep 120;
done;
sleep 120;
cat ${DONE_DIR}/isxxx*.xml;
```

Comment: Jenkins allows scheduling so I'm not sure why you don't just schedule the job every 2 minutes with an if statement and an exit status signifying whether the job is successful or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
while true;                                                                     
do                                                                              
        if [[ $(find ${DONE_DIR} -iname "issxxx*.xml") ]]; then                           
                break                                                           
        else                                                                    
                sleep 120                                                         
        fi                                                                      
done;                                                                           
sleep 120;                                                                        
cat ${DONE_DIR}/issxxx*.xml
```